# Android Contacts no longer syncs multiple accounts?

Tags: contacts, sync, google-contacts

I recently purchased a new Motorola Droid Turbo 2.  My previous phone was a Motorola Droid Turbo.  I had multiple google accounts setup. Personal and work. I could add a new contact and select which account I wanted the new contact to be associated with personal or work or other.  My new MDT2 I can not do this. I have to select an account to sync and then it can not be changed. Is there any work around or recommendations? It seems rather short sighted for Android to get rid of this feature. Running android Version 6.0

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have added both accounts to your phone under Settings -> Accounts, and enable contacts sync on each one.

While in the [Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts) app, begin adding a new contact by tapping on the "+" which brings up the "Add new contact" screen.  Directly under the contact photo, and above the contact name there is a "Saving to" box, which is a drop-down that can be accessed by tapping the down arrow to the right:
[image: Add new contact screenshot]

This drop-down should contain all your other accounts that are synced:
[image]

Select the account you wish to save this contact to by tapping on it, fill out the contact details and tap the check-mark on the top-right to save it.

Keep in mind that other contact management apps will most likely have a different way to save contacts to different accounts.